# How to call web api from mobile jquery in eclipse phonegap project

Tags: jquery, cordova

How can i call web api from mobile jquery, which i am using in eclipse phone gap project. I always get error when i call web api. Web api in made in asp.net mvc 4 & deployed in azure api management.

To call this we require to set some header, i have set all these still it executes error loop only following is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var CommonURL  = "https://mydo.azureapi.net/tcp_test/api/controllername/";
 function GetCoachProfile(UserID,AT) {
    alert('2');
    $.ajax({
        url:  CommonURL + 'GetUserProfile?UserID=' + UserID + '&AuthToken=' + AT,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',    
        dataType: 'json', 
        headers: {
            "Ocp-Apim-Trace":"true",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"bd9b6390881a4060bb2cd52b5a1d12d6"
        },
        success: function (data) {
                alert('3');
                alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
    }
    });
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: is there any errors??

Comment: Could you provide what the error is that you are getting as this may aid in solving the problem? On a GET request, it really isn't necessary to set the content type since that is used in POST-like requests. Not sure if this is causing your issue though. Seeing the error will help

Comment: on this three alert(jqXHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown); alerts first alert returns 0, second alert returns error and third error shows blank no massage .

Comment: any one have idea , y i don't get a specified error

Comment: if i changed my web api url with local web api project http://localhost:23507/api/common then my debugger get a hit, but in ajax it executes error loop

Comment: Checkout this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: thanks.my web api method return type is HttpResponseMessage, web api method get excuted successfully. But in js file ajax call executes error loop